# zio assert subtype of algebraic data type

Tags: scala, unit-testing, zio, zio-test

Given algebraic data type

```
sealed trait Result
case object Success extends Result
case class MyFailure(details: String) extends Result
```

How to assert in `zio-test` that particular value is a `Failure` and it's details contain a particular substring?

For example how to assert that below `r` is a Failure and with a `"mana"` substring?

```
val r: Result = MyFailure("not enough mana")
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the result is produced by an effect (in other words, it's wrapped by ZIO), you can use `mapError` to use the `details` in case of failure, then assert effectfully using `assertM` and `fails(containsString)`:

```scala
testM("effectfully") {
  val r = ZIO.fail(MyFailure("not enough mana")).mapError(_.details)
  
  assertM(r.run)(fails(containsString("mana")))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with `isCase`

snip:

```
  /**
   * Makes a new assertion that requires the sum type be a specified term.
   *
   * {{{
   * isCase("Some", Some.unapply, anything)
   * }}}
   */
  def isCase[Sum, Proj](
    termName: String,
    term: Sum => Option[Proj],
    assertion: Assertion[Proj]
  )
```

And my (probably not ideal) solution:

```
sealed trait Result
case object Success extends Result
case class MyFailure(details: String) extends Result

val r: Result = MyFailure("not enought mana")

test("mana") {
  assert(r)(
    isCase[Result, String](
      "details",
      { 
        case MyFailure(details) => Some(details) 
        case _                  => None
      },
      containsString("mana"))
  )
}
```

Alternatively it's possible to create a helper function and use it for such cases:

```
  def matches[A](mf: PartialFunction[A, Boolean]): Assertion[A] =
    Assertion.assertion("matches")() {
      a => mf.orElse[A, Boolean]({ case _ => false })(a)
    }
```

Now the test might look like:

```
assert(r)(
  matches {
    case MyFailure(d) => d.contains("mana")
  }
)
```